# one binary added with two internal names

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I'm trying to make an excutable file from my python code main.py using pyinstaller but i get an error and I dont know where I went wrong.

I tried different methods of pyinstaller and auto-py-to-exe, but none of them seem to work. The resulting .exe file opens a console and closes immediately.
I think its related to my imports.

```
import os
import sys
import random
import time as time
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
```

This is the messages I get on pyinstaller:

```
4951 WARNING: Hidden import "sip" not found!
....
.....
18870 WARNING: One binary added with two internal names.
18870 WARNING: ('libGLESv2.dll',
 'C:\\program '
 'files\\python36\\lib\\site-packages\\PyQt5\\Qt\\bin\\libGLESv2.dll',
 'BINARY')
18872 WARNING: was placed previously at
18872 WARNING: ('PyQt5\\Qt\\bin\\libGLESv2.dll',
 'C:\\program '
 'files\\python36\\lib\\site-packages\\PyQt5\\Qt\\bin\\libGLESv2.dll',
 'BINARY')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem by running pyinstaller --onedir main.py.

i copied the Qt5core.dll in the same folder as the generated .exe to the \PyQt\bin folder and everything was working well.